# How to export objects to parallel clusters within a function in R

Tags: r, function, parallel-processing

I am writing a function to combine and organize data then run MCMC chains in parallel using the parallel function in base R. My function is below.

```
dm100zip <- function(y, n.burn = 1, n.it = 3000, n.thin = 1) {
  y <- array(c(as.matrix(y[,2:9]), as.matrix(y[ ,10:17])), c(length(y$Plot), 8, 2))
  nplots <- nrow(y)
  ncap1 <- apply(y[,1:8, 1],1,sum)
  ncap2 <- apply(y[,1:8, 2],1,sum)
  ncap <- as.matrix(cbind(ncap1, ncap2))
  ymax1 <- apply(y[,1:8, 1],1,sum)
  ymax2 <- apply(y[,1:8, 2],1,sum)

  # Bundle data for JAGS/BUGS
  jdata100 <- list(y=y, nplots=nplots, ncap=ncap)

  # Set initial values for Gibbs sampler
  inits100 <- function(){
    list(p0=runif(1, 1.1, 2),
      p.precip=runif(1, 0, 0.1),
      p.day = runif(1, -.5, 0.1))
  }

  # Set parameters of interest to monitor and save
  params100 <- c("N", "p0")

  # Run JAGS in parallel for improved speed
  CL <- makeCluster(3) # set number of clusters = to number of desired chains
  clusterExport(cl=CL, list("jdata100", "params100", "inits100", "ymax1", "ymax2", "n.burn", "jag", "n.thin")) # make data available to jags in diff cores
  clusterSetRNGStream(cl = CL, iseed = 5312)

  out <- clusterEvalQ(CL, {
    library(rjags)
    load.module('glm')
    jm <- jags.model("dm100zip.txt", jdata100, inits100, n.adapt = n.burn, n.chains = 1)
    fm <- coda.samples(jm, params100, n.iter = n.it, thin = n.thin)
    return(as.mcmc(fm))

  })

  out.list <- mcmc.list(out) # group output from each core into one list
  stopCluster(CL)

  return(out.list)
}
```

When I run the function I get an error that n.burn, n.it, and n.thin are not found for use in the `clusterExport` function. For example,

```
dm100zip.list.nain <- dm100zip(NAIN, n.burn = 1, n.it = 3000, n.thin = 1) # returns error
```

If I set values for each of them before running the function, then it uses those values and runs fine. For example,

```
n.burn = 1
n.it = 1000
n.thin = 1
dm100zip.list.nain <- dm100zip(NAIN, n.burn = 1, n.it = 3000, n.thin = 1)
```

This runs fine but uses n.it = 1000 not 3000

Can someone help with why the objects in the global environment are used by the `ClusterExport` function but not the values assigned by the function that `ClusterExport` is run within? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default, clusterExport looks for the variables specified by "varlist" in the global environment. In your case, it should look in the local environment of the dm100zip function. To make it do that, you use the clusterExport "envir" argument:

```
clusterExport(cl=CL, list("jdata100", "params100", "inits100", "ymax1",
                          "ymax2", "n.burn", "jag", "n.thin"),
              envir=environment())
```

Note that variables in "varlist" that are defined in the global environment will also be found, but values defined in dm100zip will take precedence.

Answer (score 3):

Since function arguments in R are processed with lazy evaluation, you need to ensure that any default arguments actually exist in the function's execution environment. In fact, the R core authors included the `force` function for this purpose, which is simply `function(x) x` and forces the conversion of the argument from a promise into an evaluated expression. Try making the following modification:

```
dm100zip <- function(y, n.burn = 1, n.it = 3000, n.thin = 1) {
  force(n.burn); force(n.it); force(n.thin)
  # The rest of your code as above...
}
```

For a more detailed explanation of these issues, consult the [Lazy Evaluation section of Hadley's treatment of functions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wasn't aware of the force function. Unfortunately, I still get the same error: > dm100zip.list.nain <- dm100zip(NAIN, n.burn = 1, n.it = 3000, n.thin = 1)
Error in get(name, envir = envir) : object 'n.burn' not found
Called from: eval(substitute(browser(skipCalls = pos), list(pos = 9 - frame)), 
    envir = sys.frame(frame))

Comment: It isn't necessary to force the evaluation of variables that are exported via clusterExport. You may have to force variables that are sent to the worker processes implicitly in the serialized environment of a user supplied worker function, but that's an issue in functions such as parLapply and clusterApplyLB, not clusterEvalQ.